# Alcohol in checked-in baggage in transit through Saudi Arabia with Saudi Airlines

Tags: transit, luggage, alcohol, saudi-arabia, saudi-airlines

I am looking for cheap tickets from Germany to India via Saudi Arabia with Saudi Airlines. While I am not interested in carrying or having alcohol or any sort on board, I would like to know if it is permitted to carry it via checked-in baggage. Is that fine to do so, or is it prohibited as well? I could only find information with respect to alcohol for cabin baggage. I will be in transit at Riyadh and will not leave the airport. Googling shows people have different opinions but most of them are hunches or assumptions. Does anyone here have first-hand experience?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In addition to the ***"better safe than sorry"*** case, I finally found a link which makes it explicitly clear:

http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/SA-Saudi-Arabia-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm

> Prohibited (also for transit passengers): alcoholic beverages,
>   firearms or other lethal weapons; drugs of narcotic nature (except
>   medicines for personal use and if holding prescription); pork
>   products; natural pearls.

Hope this helps others!

Comment: What's up with pearls?

Answer (score 4):

On their website it says "SAUDIA does not serve or permit passengers to carry or drink alcoholic beverages on its flights." 
http://www.saudia.com/HOW-CAN-WE-HELP/More-Information/Terms-and-Conditions/SAUDIA-Terms-Conditions-Passenger-Advice-Notices-Liability#11430b3f2a847210VgnVCM1000001f64e80aRCRD
 I read that as meaning you may not have alcohol checked in since it amounts to carrying it.

Comment: I think that is open for interpretation. I would read the same as only restricting carry-on, but I understand why you read it the other way. I don’t think this is a definite answer yet.

Comment: Agreed. But I personally would find another way to move my alcohol, to avoid any risk of having to discuss that with KSA's famously conservative authorities.

Comment: agreed :) it’s certainly one of those “better safe than sorry” cases