# Is Saudia New York City-New Delhi flight ok?

Tags: transit, india, new-york-city, saudi-arabia, new-delhi

I have to fly from NYC-New Delhi for emergency and Saudia airlines has a flight that's $1k one way compared to $2-8K on united, american airlines, emirates.  It stops in Jeddah then onward transfer to New Delhi.

Just curious if it is safe to travel this route for any reason since the planes seem to be empty whereas every other flight is almost fully booked.

I saw similarly priced NYC-Helsinki-Doha(FINAIR)/NYC-Moscow-Delhi(AEROFOLO) but these required self-transfer and were not a good option.

Just wondering if there is a catch on the Saudi flight.

Comment: You could also check the price of a return flight on other airlines, one way tickets are often more expensive than a return.

Comment: Anyone know if passengers in transit arriving at Jeddah airport need the Tawakkalna App.  I am double vaccinated and will get a (third) booster shot this week. 
 Saudia states: "Guests traveling from Saudi Arabia's airports must present the Tawakkalna App, which shows the state of health, as this will be a condition for entering Saudi Arabia's airports, issuing boarding passes, and boarding the aircraft, according to the rules and regulations of the General Authority of Civil Aviation."

Answer (score 13):

Saudia is a major international airline with a perfectly good safety record, you shouldn’t have any trouble.

A few caveats to be aware of:

- Saudia is a completely dry airline. Alcohol is not served, and you can’t bring any in your luggage. The same goes for other things that are banned in Saudi Arabia like pork products. [This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/107384/alcohol-in-checked-in-baggage-in-transit-through-saudi-arabia-with-saudi-airline) has more details.
- If you have an Israeli passport or any evidence of travel to Israel in your passport (including relevant stamps from the Israeli borders with Egypt or Jordan), you probably won’t be allowed to fly.

Comment: +1. The inflight entertainment options are also notably lacking/censored, unless you enjoy Quran recitals you're best off bringing your own.

Comment: Thanks.  I am travelling as i have an immediate relative who is at his deathbed.  I appreciate your assistance and am booking.  I am thankful for your reply and that Saudia is not gouging passengers during this busy travel season.

Comment: I just realized why the flights are mostly empty from NYC-DELHI on Saudia:  THEY DO NOT OFFER A RETURN TRIP as far as I can see.  It's one way only from NYC-DEL.